# How to get the friend/following ids?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have written this code:

```
$twitterObj->setToken($_SESSION['ot'], $_SESSION['ots']);
$twitterFriends=$twitterObj->get_friendsIds(array('screen_name' => $_SESSION['username']));
$twitterFriends->response;
echo $twitterFriends->responseText;
foreach($twitterFriends as $friend) { echo $friend->id; }
```

But I get this:

```
{"errors":[{"code":37,"message":"Not authorized to use this endpoint"}]}
```

Why ?
How can I get the friend/following ids ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2114) you could be using old twitter API URL's. Have you tried updating the twitter library your using?